# why iconv can not convert a character

Tags: utf-8, iconv, gb2312

I got this error. Do anybody know what is wrong? Thanks.

```
$ wget -qO- http://yjs.cd120.com/daoshi-2.html| iconv -f gb2312 -t utf-8 > /dev/null
iconv: (stdin):430:173: cannot convert
```

Comment: Because the file has invalid encoding for gb2312 at that position in the file. If you use GBK (extension of GB2312) as the source encoding it works.